# LoopingSelector doesn't show up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the `LoopingSelector` as shown in this tutorial: [WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API).  I just copied their XAML and C# code.  I modified the XAML a bit to fit my layout but it's still similar to their tutorial though.

Here is my XAML code where I put the LoopingSelector:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Countdown Time" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="28" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector x:Name="hSelector"
                               ItemMargin="2,3,3,2" ItemSize="100,100" />
            <TextBlock Text=":" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="64"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource Digital7}"/>
            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector x:Name="mSelector"
                               ItemMargin="2,3,3,2" ItemSize="100,100" />
            <TextBlock Text="'" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="64"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource Digital7}"/>
            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector x:Name="sSelector"
                               ItemMargin="2,3,3,2" ItemSize="100,100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

where `toolkitPrimitives` is defined as:

```
xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assem‌​bly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

And here is what I did in the code behind:

```
this.hSelector.DataSource = new IntLoopingDataSource()
{
    MinValue = 0,
    MaxValue = 23,
    SelectedItem = 0
};
this.mSelector.DataSource = new IntLoopingDataSource()
{
    MinValue = 0,
    MaxValue = 59,
    SelectedItem = 1
};
this.sSelector.DataSource = new IntLoopingDataSource()
{
    MinValue = 0,
    MaxValue = 59,
    SelectedItem = 0
};
```

I would have used `TimePicker` instead however it doesn't support picking `Second`. I need to pick Hour, Minute, *and* Second.

Comment: I declare toolkitPrimitives namespace as this
xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to set `Width` and `Height` and `ItemSize` on the looping selector.** This control doesn't handle cases without an absolute size very well. That's why it doesn't work in a StackPanel.

StackPanels provide an infinite width and height.

Normally controls are supposed to handle those cases, but being a primitive control, they've made the assumption that those values will be set.

Answer (score 2):

Through some experiments, I found out that, for some unknown reasons, LoopingSelector doesn't like StackPanel at all. If you want to have many LoopingSelector, the best way to achieve it is making a grid.

Here is my modified XAML:

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="Countdown Time" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" />
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector Grid.Column="0" x:Name="hSelector" ItemMargin="2,3,3,2" ItemSize="100,100" Height="300"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text=":" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="64" FontFamily="{StaticResource Digital7}"/>
                            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector Grid.Column="2" x:Name="mSelector" ItemMargin="2,3,3,2" ItemSize="100,100" Height="300"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="'" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="64" FontFamily="{StaticResource Digital7}" />
                            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector Grid.Column="4" x:Name="sSelector" ItemMargin="2,3,3,2" ItemSize="100,100" Height="300"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

p.s. for someone who's familiar with StackOverflow, please help me format those XAML in my post because I don't know how to format it correctly.